# moving js and css to the footer

Tags: javascript, css, optimization

Google page speed insights want me to fix  "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexam-paper.net%2Fqa&tab=desktop

When I moved js and css to the footer and checked with chrome inspect elements it shows a lot of function not defined error which I guess is happening because the js required for those function are loaded later.

So can I ignore those errors or they could affect my site functionality ?

My site http://exam-paper.net

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help]. Your question must be **self-contained**, it cannot rely on a link to your site, because your question will become useless to other people as soon as you update your site. Build an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and post it **in** the question.

Answer (score 1):

It happens cause you have some scripts within body. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#quick_login input[name='url']").val($(location).attr('href'));
</script>
```

This code provokes error if jQuery not loaded yet. And it will affect your site functionality of course.